# kubernetes redis cluster master IP changed automatic

Tags: kubernetes

When I am add a master nodes into redis cluster using this command:

```
cluster meet 172.30.184.15 6379
```

then the master nodes add failed and the IP changed, the result is:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> cluster nodes
7120d797d6be60d31c0f49580d19e9fd0a6e1fba 172.30.224.23:6379@16379 slave 567d4a90ed9a7eb9e2595b4c052cc611da9bd684 0 1582512862000 5 connected
853ddd328f7eebd9577abe89103ce693f5fe0834 172.30.184.0:6379@16379 master,fail - 1582512683516 1582512683117 4 disconnected
7df21aad1564f14203bc1bc172f6be6c3380ea36 172.30.208.5:6379@16379 master - 0 1582512863050 3 connected
c992f013eccc7e72105f130fdbd4e7abf3d6e5b0 172.30.208.6:6379@16379 slave 7df21aad1564f14203bc1bc172f6be6c3380ea36 0 1582512862448 3 connected
567d4a90ed9a7eb9e2595b4c052cc611da9bd684 172.30.224.22:6379@16379 myself,master - 0 1582512861000 5 connected 0-10922
```

The IP address changed from `172.30.184.15` to `172.30.184.0`, why would this happen? what should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

How you deploy redis on k8s?

also add using hostname not Pod IP.

You can check here my github repo for redis deployment on k8s.

[Redis deploy on kubernetes](https://github.com/pawankkamboj/redis-k8s)